# Как скачать фото по прямой ссылке JAVA

Tags: java

Никак не получается скачать фото по ссылке.  Есть прямая ссылка. Нужно скачать фото и записать в файл на компьютере. Я не могу прописать правильный синтаксис Get запроса так, чтобы в ответе сохранить фото правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
 public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String dowloadFolder) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
        String name = url.toString().substring(url.toString().lastIndexOf("/"), url.toString().lastIndexOf("."));
        String extension = url.toString().substring(url.toString().lastIndexOf("."), url.toString().length());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dowloadFolder + name + extension);
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
    }
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
```

Решил проблему, кому пригодится вот.

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
        String name = url.toString().substring(url.toString().lastIndexOf("/"), url.toString().lastIndexOf("."));
        String extension = url.toString().substring(url.toString().lastIndexOf("."), url.toString().length());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dowloadFolder + name + extension);
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221979/reading-binary-file-from-urlconnection

Comment: Что значит "никак не получается"? Возникант ошибка? Покажите её полный текст и ваш код.

Comment: При подключении выдает ошибку 403